# Transform manipulator is not aligning with transform orientation

Tags: transform-orientation, 3d-manipulator

I am on Blender version 4.0.2.

I am attempting to make transformations on an object while using global orientation. To my understanding, when you switch transform orientations, the transform manipulator should align with the new orientation. However, when I switch to Global orientation, the manipulator does not align itself. In this image, I would expect the green arrow (Y axis of transformation) to be parallel with the green line (global Y axis) on the left and similar with the red arrow/line (X axis):

[image]

When I press G to move and Y to constrain the axes of movement, I thankfully get the correct axis of movement, but it is clearly different than the Y axis of the transform manipulator:

[image]

Since I am able to get the correct movement, I can still work; however, it does complicate the process of more complex movement. For example, if I create a custom orientation from the normal of a face that is oriented in a random direction, like in the image below.. :

[image]

.. I sometimes need visual confirmation that the orientation is correct.  Instead, what I get is a transform manipulator that still points in some arbitrary direction rather than aligning with the orientation of the selected face that was used to create the transform orientation:

[image]

If this is just a lack of understanding on my part, I am open to being educated! Otherwise, help with aligning the transform manipulator with the active transform orientation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe make sure that the *Orientation* on the top left is set to *Default* so that it takes the selected *Transformation Orientation* into account:

[image]

Comment: aaaand my problem is immediately solved!  You rock moonboots